# How to get "tail -f" working on a file located on a Windows share

Tags: windows, mac-osx, network-share, terminal, tail

I'm using a Mac and I have mounted a Windows network disk in my file system using "Connect to Server" in the Finder.

In the terminal when i do tail -f on a log file located on said network disk, tail is not updating the display when new lines are written to the log file. I'm assuming that tail normally listens to some os event when the file is updated and that this is not working when tailing files on a network drive.

How to solve this problem? Another program?

Comment: `tail` normally watches for changes in file size; maybe these are not reported by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

sendmoreinfo is right, `tail` watches for changes in file size. Sometimes this does not happen correctly on mac clients (especially when samba is involved). I ended my search in this phenomenon after two days, the mac smb client is just wired sometimes (ever tried to connect to shares with signature check twice?).